# Validation failed due to manually inserted value

Tags: html, angularjs, validation

Value of filename is being manually inserted using this

```
<input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="document.getElementById('fileName').value = this.value.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop()" required>
```

Filename is being injected into fileName field using the file a user chooses. Validation fails as it treats that field as still being empty until I at least insert one more character. What can I do to fix that?

This is the validation part

```
<p ng-show="fileNameForm.fileNameInput.$error.required && fileNameForm.fileNameInput.$touched" class="help-block">File name is required.</p>
```

And the actual text field

```
<input name="fileNameInput" class="form-control" type="text" id="fileName" ng-model="document.fileName" ng-maxlength="255" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

on change will not be evaluated if the model is changed programmatically and not by a change to the input value

you can use $scope.$watch to detect changes on ng-model

```
$scope.$watch('document.fileName', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  //if(newValue not valid)
  //    display validation error
});
```

Comment: I don't understand what to do with this bit of code. I put it in the controller but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: since you are setting file name programmatically onchange will not be able to detect changes to document.fileName. For this reason you can use $scope.$watch to detect changes. Inside $scope.$watch you can check newValue to see if it contains a valid fileName or not and set condition for validation message accordingly.

Comment: Even with a watch on the model it only recognises manual input from keyboard and not fileName being programmatically inserted. Watch treats it like nothing has happened, like nothing was inserted.

Comment: check the value of newValue inside watch to see the new value of fileName

Comment: $scope.$watch('document.fileName', function(newValue, oldValue) {

          console.log(oldValue);
          console.log(newValue);
          
      });

Comment: are they empty?

Comment: Okay, it only recognises the keyboard input. $watch is not aware of any changes made by "document.getElementById('fileName').value = this.value.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop()"

Comment: thats because you are using document.getElementById to access element, you should use $scope.fileName

Comment: document is necessary here. My app is about uploading and saving documents. That's why it's called document.fileName. AngularJS document has nothing to do with this